# SQL divide subquery within a table

Tags: mysql, division

This might have been already answered but I couldn't find anything that points me in the right direction. I would appreciate any help.

I am using a table called `order_items` which is looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|  id                 order_id   status  |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2014001            1          complete |
| 2014002            1          canceled |
| 2014003            3          complete |
| 2014004            4          canceled |
| 2014005            1          canceled |
| 2014006            1          complete |
| 2014007            2          canceled |
| 2014008            3          complete |
+----------------------------------------+
```

`order_items.id` is the primary key. I want to write a query that will find the percentage of `order_items` with `complete` status within each `order_id`
so the results should be something like this:

```
+----------------------------+
| Percentage        order_id |
+----------------------------+
| .5                   1     |
| 0                    2     |
| 1                    3     |
| 0                    4     |
+----------------------------+
```

This is the code I'm trying, but it isn't working

```
select  
order_items.order_id ,
(select count(order_items.status) from order_items where order_items.status='complete')/ count(order_items.status)
from order_items 
GROUP BY order_items.order_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using conditional aggregation:

```
select oi.order_id, avg(oi.status = 'complete')
from order_items oi
group by oi.order_id;
```

`oi.status` returns true, which is treated like 1 in a numeric context.  The average of this over all the rows is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. I should look into the subject to understand it more.

Comment: I chose the stupid way :)

select sum(complete) / sum(total) as percentage, order_id
from (
select order_id, count(order_id) as complete, 0 as total
from order_items
where status = 'complete'
group by order_id
union
select order_id, 0 as complete, count(order_id) as total
from order_items
group by order_id
 ) s
 group by s.order_id;

Try it out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e562a/6) - you can also test the others right away :)

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if that works

```
select

order_items.order_id ,
 (select count(order_items.id) from order_items 
where order_items.status=  'complete')/ count(order_items.id)
from order_items 
GROUP BY order_items.order_id
```

Comment: it show the same results as my query, i think it counts all of rows with complete status in the table and divide it by the number that are in the group. i,e, . it only applies the grouping to divisor.